# React Redux state array variable pass as prop to child component, either infinite loop or empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I am passing Redux state variable collection as props to PokeList.js,
using the useEffect hook to set state, but if I set props.collection as dependency
the array map function sees the props.collection as empty array, since I tried to 
log out pokeData in the map function and gets nothing, if I remove the
props.collection dependency, it creates an infinite loop situation, I can console.log
the props.collection, which shows an empty array first, then the correct array,
how do I set the state correctly?

I have tried dispatching in PokeList.js, which has the same result,
also tried dirrectly initialize cardList = props.collection.map... but
get cardList undefined,
also tried using React.memo and set props as dependency
doesn't work either

```
//PokeList.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';

const PokeList = (props) => {
    const [cardList, setCardList] = useState();
    console.log(props.collection)

    useEffect(() => {
        var newCardList = props.collection.map(pokeData => { 
            console.log(pokeData)
            return (
                <Card key={pokeData.id} style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                    <Card.Img variant="top" src={pokeData.sprite} />
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title>{pokeData.Name}</Card.Title>
                        <ListGroup className="list-group-flush">
                            <ListGroup.Item>{'Height: ' + pokeData.height}</ListGroup.Item>
                            <ListGroup.Item>{'Weight: ' + pokeData.weight}</ListGroup.Item>
                        </ListGroup>
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            )})
        setCardList(newCardList)
    }, [props.collection])

    return (
        <div>
           {cardList}
        </div>
    )
}

export default PokeList;

//Search.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import PokeList from './pokedex/PokeList';
import * as pokedexActions from './pokedex/actions/PokedexActions';

const Search = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(pokedexActions.getLimitNames(5))
    }, [dispatch])

    const collection = useSelector(state => state.pokedex.collection);

    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <h2>Search</h2>
                <PokeList collection={collection}/>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Search;

// reducer.js
import { GET_LIMIT_NAMES } from '../actions/PokedexActions';

const initialState = {
    collection: []
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_LIMIT_NAMES:
            return {
                collection: action.data
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
// action.js
import Pokemon from '../Pokemon';

export const GET_LIMIT_NAMES = "GET_LIMIT_NAMES";

export const getLimitNames = (limit = 100) => {
    // redux-thunk
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            const allResponse = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=${limit}`);
            const allUrlsData = await allResponse.json();
            // console.log(allUrlsData.results);

            const collection = [];

            Promise.all(allUrlsData.results.map(urlData => {
                var pokemon;
                fetch(urlData.url).then(resp =>
                    resp.json()
                ).then(data => {
                    // console.log(data);
                    pokemon = new Pokemon(data);
                    // pokemon.log();
                    collection.push(pokemon)
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
                return collection;
            }))

            // console.log(collection)

            dispatch({
                type: GET_LIMIT_NAMES,
                data: collection
            });

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
};
```

if I try to directly render the map result, nothing appeared, the map function
still only gets the empty array,

```
// PokeList.js
import React from 'react';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';
import './Pokedex.css'

const PokeList = (props) => {
    console.log('props.collection', props.collection)

    return (
        // <div className='poke-list'>
        //    {cardList}
        // </div>
        <div className='poke-list'>
            {props.collection.map(pokeData => {
                return (
                    <Card key={pokeData.id} style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
                        <Card.Img variant="top" src={pokeData.sprite} />
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title>{pokeData.Name}</Card.Title>
                            <ListGroup className="list-group-flush">
                                <ListGroup.Item>{"Height: " + pokeData.height}</ListGroup.Item>
                                <ListGroup.Item>{"Weight: " + pokeData.weight}</ListGroup.Item>
                            </ListGroup>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default PokeList;
```

[image]

if I remove the [props.collection] dependency, it creates the infinite loop
situation, but the components are rendering
[image]

Comment: Why are you mapping it in useEffect? Did you try to just return that map or set it in a var without useEffect? If you do that, it will not do anything will array is empty and will do the job when is filled in next render

Comment: You don't need `useState` or `useEffect` in PokeList, as Adolfo says just render the cards directly

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that every time `Search` renders, `collection` is created and passed to `PokeList`. Then `PokeList` is using that `collection` (new on every render, remember) and using it as a dependency of your hook. This means that every time `Search` renders, the hook in `PokeList` will run.

Simply use `collection` prop to render the Component tree inside `PokeList`:

```
const PokeList = props => {
    console.log(props.collection);

    return (
        <div>
            {props.collection.map(pokeData => {
                return (
                    <Card key={pokeData.id} style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
                        <Card.Img variant="top" src={pokeData.sprite} />
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title>{pokeData.Name}</Card.Title>
                            <ListGroup className="list-group-flush">
                                <ListGroup.Item>{"Height: " + pokeData.height}</ListGroup.Item>
                                <ListGroup.Item>{"Weight: " + pokeData.weight}</ListGroup.Item>
                            </ListGroup>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: I tried that, but nothing appeared, the map function still recieves the empty array,
and not the updated one

Comment: @impressiveHen the Search hook with `dispatch` is a bit strange. What is `pokedexActions.getLimitNames(5)` exactly returning?

Comment: Hi, I added the action.js in the new edit, it returns an array of my defined class Pokemon objects which has the instance id, name, ...

Comment: @impressiveHen, I think there is the issue. `pokedexActions.getLimitNames(5)` is returning a function that needs to receive a dispatch function. Replace that hook with: `useEffect(() => { pokedexActions.getLimitNames(5)(dispatch); }, []);` and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I replaced my hook in Search.js as you said but it's still empty,
https://github.com/impressiveHen/Pokedex this is my repo link，if you want
to test it your self, thank you for answering my questions

Comment: @impressiveHen, no problem. Does collection ever get all the values? Looking at `getLimitNames` Im not sure if its doing things correctly. I think that inside `Promise.all` `.map` what should be returned is the `fetch`. Also `Promise.all` might need an await: `await Promise.all(allUrlsData.results.map(urlData => {var pokemon; return fetch(//...`.

Comment: I think getLimitNames is working correctly since I did get the array I wanted,
since I log props.collections and it gives me what I wanted
it's just that by dirrectly setting cardList in PokeList.js, it doesn't seem to update, when props.collection updated

Answer (score 0):

turns out the problem is in Acions.js Problem.all
by changing into for loop and await for all fetches solves the 
not empty array problem

```
for (var i=0; i<allUrlsData.results.length; i++) {
                const res = await fetch(allUrlsData.results[i].url)
                const resData = await res.json()
                const pokemon = new Pokemon(resData)
                collection.push(pokemon)
            }
```